# Need to create a C# WebAPI endpoint to accept JSON string by post

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create a single endpoint in a C# ASP.NET Core Web API that will receive a JSON string.

The JSON string could represent many possible actions, for example:

- Providing details of a product
- Providing details of a person
- Providing details of xxx

The idea is that my endpoint would receive this JSON, inspect it, identify what "type" of operation this is and then proceed.

So, what I need to do is to create this endpoint. Sounds simple enough, but I'm getting errors.

**Postman client**

In the Postman client, I'm using to test this, my body is a valid json string:

```
{
    "eventType": "Blah",
    "propertyOne": "Blah 1",
    "timestamp": 1629804577002
}
```

I'm sending this as "raw" with the type as `json` (so the `Content-Type` is "application/json").

**Web API**

My controller has this method in it:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
   // ...
}
```

However, I can't find the incoming string of JSON.

Normally, if the Json structure was constant, I'd create a class of that type and have that as an argument. But I don't know the type...

I thought of having:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(JsonElement data)
```

But this returns an error:

> The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

Surely this should be trivial, but I'm just not seeing it.

---

### Solved

My problem was that I was reading the Request.Body in the middleware and hadn't rewound the stream.  Beginners error.  Anyhow, it's loading directly into the `JsonElement` as wanted.

Comment: Typically, you create a POCO object that mimics the JSON.  And that is the input-parameter-TYPE of the HttpPost.  And asp.net-core..behind the scenes does the mapping to the POCO.  See : https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/        OR (less preferred to the strong POCO) you can do this : https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers But I think you want a strong-custom-poco over a JsonElement IMHO.

Comment: Understand about the POCO, but as mentioned, the structure of the JSON is so variable that this isn't an option.

Comment: Be weary of the "Command Pattern". (accept anything....and decide what to do with it).  It is "never done"....and violates many SOLID principles IMHO.  https://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern  This example throws a magic string for + or - or * or /   .   Or if you "inspect the payload" for find the corresponding do-something-with-it "command".   The "never done-ness" of this pattern makes it too fragile IMHO.    if you go forward... you should put in very clean "single responsibility" items at the beginning..for it'll go big-ball-of-mudd quickly.

Comment: for example :     the code that decides which command to run should be separated from the commands themselves.

Comment: You've been warned.  It sounds "oh so clever" in the beginning.....but the bug potential and fragility of the "never done entry point".........just not a fan of it at all.